# Can't ping remote address or domain in Tails

Tags: tails

When I try to ping an external address I always get the same error: "Destination Port Unreachable", and when pinging domain names I get an "unknown host" message.

I have Tails 1.6 and run tor when connected to the internet, also i'm using terminal to ping.

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

The `ping` tool uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets, which are **not** supported by Tor, and therefore can't be sent from within Tails. (Tor supports only [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) as its transport layer protocol.)

For TCP-based alternatives, you could take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/14376/ping-alternative-for-tcp) thread. Note that to install any [additional software](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/additional_software/index.en.html) on Tails, you'd first need to ensure that an [admin account](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/startup_options/administration_password/index.en.html) has been created.